# Centering a group of QML widgets without changing their relative alignment

Tags: qt, qml

### The short version

I'd like to horizontally and/or vertically center groups of QML widgets without being forced to align them in a structured layout.

### The long version

I made the following design:

[image: Design]

My QML code so far is as follows. (I know the hardcoded X/Y coordinates are sloppy, it's just a mockup.)

```
import QtQuick 2.12
import QtQuick.Window 2.12
import QtQuick.Shapes 1.11
import QtQuick.Controls 2.3
import QtQuick.Layouts 1.0

Window {
    id: window
    visible: true
    width: 640
    height: 480
    color: "#f0eded"
    title: qsTr("Hello World")

    Image {
        id: image
        x: 215
        y: 96
        sourceSize.height: 210
        sourceSize.width: 210
        source: "lock.svg"
    }

    Text {
        id: element
        y: 364
        anchors.horizontalCenter: parent.horizontalCenter
        color: "#646464"
        text: qsTr("Unlock your rclone configuration to continue.")
        anchors.horizontalCenterOffset: 0
        styleColor: "#00000000"
        horizontalAlignment: Text.AlignHCenter
        font.pixelSize: 12
    }

    TextField {
        id: txtPassword
        x: 193
        y: 312
        focus: true
        font.pointSize: 22
        horizontalAlignment: Text.AlignHCenter
        echoMode: TextInput.Password
    }

    Button {
        id: btnContinue
        x: 399
        y: 312
        width: txtPassword.height
        height: txtPassword.height
        text: qsTr("»")
        background: Rectangle {
            border.color: btnContinueMouse.containsMouse ? "#cdcdcd" : "#ccc"
            color: btnContinueMouse.containsMouse ? "#eee" : "#ddd"
        }

        MouseArea {
           id: btnContinueMouse
           anchors.fill: parent
           hoverEnabled: true
        }
    }
}
```

What I'd like to do is to horizontally and vertically center this group of widgets so that its alignment still makes sense if a user increases the size of the window. I know I can put widgets into a row/column/grid layout for such purposes, but then I lose a lot of control over the space between the widgets.

What approach would you recommend to turn this mockup into clean QML code while staying true to the original design?

Comment: What a problem to wrap all the items with one of `Layouts` or `Item` if even you call it _group of items_? That the only right and true way to layout the form components. With full control on spacing etc if you will do that right. Otherwise I think the only way is absolute positioning.

Comment: I thought you had to align widgets into a row/column/grid to use a layout and I wasn't aware that you could use `Item` for this purpose.

Comment: I still advice you to use one of `Layout`s instead of `Item` since you can position items inside it in much more convenient and _right_ way that anchoring.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Two ways:

Wrap it in an Item, then

Use anchors to position your content relative to the screen like this:

```
Item {
        anchors.fill: parent
    Image {
        id: image

        anchors.left: parent.left
        anchors.right: parent.right
        sourceSize.height: 210
        sourceSize.width: 210
        source: "lock.svg"
    }

    Text {
        id: element
        anchors.top:  txtPassword.bottom
        anchors.left: txtPassword.left
        anchors.right: btnContinue.right



        color: "#646464"
        text: qsTr("Unlock your rclone configuration to continue.")

        styleColor: "#00000000"
        horizontalAlignment: Text.AlignHCenter
        font.pixelSize: 12
    }
```

---

### OR

Create separate components out of the different parts then place them as a whole into a layout. Do this by moving your elements into a separate file then referencing that file using its name:

example:

```
LockElement  { anchors.centerIn: parent }
```

will load `LockElement.qml`  which will have your Item, Image, TextBox etc all in one file.

This will make the coordinates relative to their own coordinate space.

### LockElement.qml

```
import QtQuick 2.12
import QtQuick.Window 2.12
import QtQuick.Shapes 1.11
import QtQuick.Controls 2.3
import QtQuick.Layouts 1.0

 Item {

   width: 640
   height: 480


    Image {
        id: image
        x: 215
        y: 96
        sourceSize.height: 210
        sourceSize.width: 210
        source: "lock.svg"
    }

    Text {
        id: element
        y: 364
        anchors.horizontalCenter: parent.horizontalCenter
        color: "#646464"
        text: qsTr("Unlock your rclone configuration to continue.")
        anchors.horizontalCenterOffset: 0
        styleColor: "#00000000"
        horizontalAlignment: Text.AlignHCenter
        font.pixelSize: 12
    }

    TextField {
        id: txtPassword
        x: 193
        y: 312
        focus: true
        font.pointSize: 22
        horizontalAlignment: Text.AlignHCenter
        echoMode: TextInput.Password
    }

    Button {
        id: btnContinue
        x: 399
        y: 312
        width: txtPassword.height
        height: txtPassword.height
        text: qsTr("»")
        background: Rectangle {
            border.color: btnContinueMouse.containsMouse ? "#cdcdcd" : "#ccc"
            color: btnContinueMouse.containsMouse ? "#eee" : "#ddd"
        }

        MouseArea {
           id: btnContinueMouse
           anchors.fill: parent
           hoverEnabled: true
        }
    }
}
 // etc..
```

---

Comment: Yes, that looks like what I need! Didn't know you could use `Item` for this. Thanks!